# Software Process using TFS

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to implement a software process using MSF for CMMI to govern all software pojects in my company using TFS. Is there a reference example you are aware of for a company that went into the same excercise of managing requirements using VSTS along with a 3rd party tool, implement configuration management and change management, define policies for automated builds & CIs, automataed deployment, custom project portals and reports. Is there something that shows a full lifecycle process implementation and practicies through TFS.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but you may want to listen to [Radio TFS #18](http://www.radiotfs.com/2009/03/25/AdoptingTeamSystemWithStevenBorg.aspx), which covers the topic of different process models and their adoption.